# How can I hide php file extension using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^site/index$ site/index.php [NC,L]
```

this line does hide the extension successfully. Now I do not want the page with the extension to be accessible; if one tries to access that page with the extension, it must show an error. Only the one that has the extension hidden that must be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MrWhite gave an answer that showed how to throw an error message like you asked, but why would you want to throw an error message instead of just redirecting `example.com/page.php` to `example.com/page`? Here is the .htaccess code for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

This makes sure that both `/page` and `/page.php` go to the same url (`/page`) and serve the same page/file (`/page.php`)

Comment: Now I want to exclude only one page; I do not want its extension removed, how can I modify the above solution?

Answer (score 1):

> it must show an error.

To return a 403 Forbidden when accessing `/site/index.php` you could do the following *before* the existing rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^site/index\.php$ - [F]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` is necessary in order to prevent the rewritten URL also triggering a 403.

However, it would be more SEO-friendly to redirect/correct such requests instead.

*Aside:*

> this line does hide the extension successfully.

Just wording I guess, but "this line" doesn't "hide" anything. It specifically adds the extension back. (The extension is already hidden in the initial request.)